# WebView + addJavascriptInterface + javascript = issues, webcore crashes

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I use **WebView** + **addJavascriptInterface** to control my app from html page shown in a WebView control.
It works fine on some API versions, but for example on API 10 in emulator it behaves wrong, **crashes** are seen in **WebViewCoreThread**. Also reported by users on some real devices.

My html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideId(id){
   callback.hide(id);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Hide" onclick="hideId('1');">
</body>
</html>
```

This shows a Hide button, which should call back my Java code, which looks like this:

```
private class JS{
   public void hide(String id){
      ... some code
   }
}

WebView wv = ...
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JS(), "callback");
wv.loadURL(...);
```

It works fine on some devices, but on mentioned API10 emulator, after pressing the button in html, logcat shows error, and entire WebView becomes ill, no more controls react to touches, and my JS.hide function is not called.

```
W/dalvikvm(1790): JNI WARNING: jarray 0xb6e1bfd0 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
I/dalvikvm(1790): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
I/dalvikvm(1790):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb6e4f8a0 self=0x8a9c568
I/dalvikvm(1790):   | sysTid=1800 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=145332280
I/dalvikvm(1790):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(1790):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(1790):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:53)
I/dalvikvm(1790):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1158)
I/dalvikvm(1790):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
I/dalvikvm(1790):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
I/dalvikvm(1790):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
I/dalvikvm(1790):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
E/dalvikvm(1790): VM aborting
```

Any idea what is wrong with this?

Comment: It sure looks fine. It is not that dissimilar from some of the samples that I have used in books, like: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/WebView/GeoWeb1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across this problem myself as well and I found that this is a known issue for android 2.3. 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987

Comment: Helpful link, it made me to redesign code to use WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading instead of javascript callbacks

Comment: The solution provided in the link is not fully synchronous. I've provided a better and more fleshed out fix in my comment below.